# How to implement a trait method that returns a trait object (of a different trait)

Tags: rust, trait-objects

I'm studying Rust, and I'm struggling to replicate some OOP pattern using Rust's traits.

Briefly, I'd like to know what is Rust's way to solve this kind of problem. I have an interface whose methods return objects of another interface. Talking about a particular example, a trait Population contains referneces to objets that implement the `Human` trait.

I'm not sure at what stage I should use `Person` instead of `Human`, because I have tried several ways to implement this, and I always end with some issue. Or maybe I'm missing some special syntax that is mandatory to implement this schema in Rust.

I've come up with this code example to show what I try to do:

```
use rand::{distributions::Alphanumeric, Rng};
use std::fmt;
trait Population {
    fn get_a_human(&self) -> &Box<dyn Human>;
}

trait Human {
    fn say_my_name(&self) -> &str;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Person {
    name: String,
}

impl Person {
    fn new(name: &str) -> Person {
        Person {
            name: String::from(name),
        }
    }
}

impl Human for Person {
    fn say_my_name(&self) -> &str {
        &self.name
    }
}

impl fmt::Debug for dyn Human {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        f.debug_tuple("").field(&self.say_my_name()).finish()
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct City {
    city_name: String,
    pop: Vec<Box<dyn Human>>,
}

impl City {
    fn new(name: &str, pop: Vec<Box<dyn Human>>) -> City {
        City {
            city_name: String::from(name),
            pop,
        }
    }
}

impl Population for City {
    fn get_a_human(&self) -> &Box<dyn Human> {
        &self.pop[0]
    }
}

fn add_rnd_pop() -> Vec<Box<Person>> {
    let mut v = Vec::new();

    for _ in 0..10 {
        let name: String = rand::thread_rng()
            .sample_iter(&Alphanumeric)
            .take(7)
            .map(char::from)
            .collect();

        v.push(Box::new(Person::new(&name)));
    }

    v
}

fn main() {
    let pop = add_rnd_pop();
    let cordoba = City::new("Cordoba", pop);

    println!("A person's name from Córdoba: {:?}", cordoba.get_a_human());
}
```

Comment: "I'm struggling to replicate some OOP pattern using Rust's traits" - that is a bad start.

Comment: [`&Box` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/7884305). Return `&dyn Human` instead.

Comment: Rust cannot automatically convert `Vec<Box<Person>>` to `Vec<Box<dyn Human>>`. You need to return `Vec<Box<dyn Human>>` from `add_rnd_pop()`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman But If I return `Vec<Box<dyn Human>>` I get an error when I push elements into the vector within `add_rnd_pop()` because I try to push Persons and the compiler expects Humans. It's really confusing because I'd expect it to detect that a Person implements the Human interface, so If I apply your proposal, I'd get: 
` fn add_rnd_pop() -> Vec<Box<(dyn Human + 'static)>>` and `v.push(Box::new(Person::new(&name)));` as changes, but still I get errors because of the impossible automatic convert.

Comment: This is an inference quirk. Specify the `Vec` type inside the function: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b46f1b85f0076b4541b83189591c1635.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman that made it! Thank you very much for helping with it.